# Excel vba code to repetively move a group of cells

Tags: excel, vba

Here's a sample of the first 6 lines, 4 columns wide:

```
25  50  100 250
A08000FLTPHIL0.250  A08000FLTPHIL0.250  A08000FLTPHIL0.250  A08000FLTPHIL0.250
7.79    7.35    6.92    6.49
25  50  100 250
A08000FLTSCKT0.250  A08000FLTSCKT0.250  A08000FLTSCKT0.250  A08000FLTSCKT0.250
7.79    7.35    6.92    6.49
```

I need it to end up in this order, 3 columns wide:

```
25  A08000FLTPHIL0.250  7.79
50  A08000FLTPHIL0.250  7.35
100 A08000FLTPHIL0.250  6.92
250 A08000FLTPHIL0.250  6.49
25  A08000FLTSCKT0.250  7.79
50  A08000FLTSCKT0.250  7.35
100 A08000FLTSCKT0.250  6.92
250 A08000FLTSCKT0.250  6.49
```

There are 5200 rows. It's too much to manually cut and paste.

Yes, I realize there is repetitive information. It is the nature of the data I am being provided and must be used and formatted as it is shown

The objective is to build a discount table which I will then import into MySQL for "Ecommerce Templates" an e-commerce program.

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

We can't write the code for you (this is not the site for that). We can help you solve issues or provide general answers.

You should write a for loop in VBA which scans all the rows of you source worksheet and in rows for which Mod 3 = 1 it should paste values to column 1, rows for Mod 3 = 2 to column 2 and rows for which Mod 3 = 0 to column 3.

Here are some links to start you off:

1. For loops: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/5z06z1kb.aspx
2. Offsetting rows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx
3. Modulo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/se0w9esz.aspx

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I truly appreciate your help.